# fastest way to locate elements selenium+java

Tags: java, performance, selenium, element

I need to check my site for invalid tooltips and other error mesages on my site during the tests to make sure everything is okey. the problem is that selenium seem to take forever to find these elements and they are set on a timer so they sometimes have time to disapere before selenium finds them, we are talking about a 3 second timer.

right now I find them like so:

```
      List<WebElement> error = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.alert .error"));
        if (error.size() == 0) {return true;}
        else {return false;}
```

this will find all the error messages that are shown on the site at the given time and this is sometimes to slow to keep up. the tooltips are created and destroyd with javascript so they are not hidden and then displayed. Any thoughts on this?

EDIT:

Since the site is single page it's a massive amount of elements to go through to find the right one, altho it's fast when I look for a item that is actually vissable so to minimize my search I did like this:

```
WebElement messages = driver.findElement(By.id("the-div-the-message-is-created-in"));
List<WebElement> error = messages.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.alert .error"));
if (error.size() == 0) {return true;}
else {return false;}
```

altho it didn't seem to verify the existence of the element it any faster.

Comment: How many elements are we talking about here?

Comment: there shoulden't be more then 1 or 2 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I put in every single framework i've ever built, which is VERY efficient.. Here is an exerpt from the framework found [here](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium). [You can download it here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/archive/master.zip)...

I implement sort of a pseudo-wait type method before i ever perform any actions on objects.  Try it yourself.  It's very efficient.

These are methods from the [AutomationTest](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/blob/master/src/main/java/com/company/seleniumframework/AutomationTest.java) class

```
    /**
     * Checks if the element is present or not.<br>
     * @param by
     * @return <i>this method is not meant to be used fluently.</i><br><br.
     * Returns <code>true</code> if the element is present. and <code>false</code> if it's not.
     */
    public boolean isPresent(By by) {
        if (driver.findElements(by).size() > 0) return true;
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Private method that acts as an arbiter of implicit timeouts of sorts.. sort of like a Wait For Ajax method.
     */
    private WebElement waitForElement(By by) {
        int attempts = 0;
        int size = driver.findElements(by).size();

        while (size == 0) {
            size = driver.findElements(by).size();
            if (attempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS) fail(String.format("Could not find %s after %d seconds",
                                                             by.toString(),
                                                             MAX_ATTEMPTS));
            attempts++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second.
            } catch (Exception x) {
                fail("Failed due to an exception during Thread.sleep!");
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (size > 0) System.err.println("WARN: There are more than 1 " + by.toString() + " 's!");

        return driver.findElement(by);
    }
```

Combine these methods yourself, and you're good to go.

#### ALSO

In terms of performance, I cannot stress to you this enough.. **USE CSS**.  It is faster, and cleaner.  See for yourself.

Consider the following,

```
<div id="something">
  <div class="someClass">
    <a href='http://google.com/search?'>Search Google</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let's find the `<a>`.

CSS:

```
div#something div.someClass > a[href^='http://google']
```

XPATH:

```
//div[@id='something']/div[contains(@class, 'someClass')]/a[starts-with(@href, 'http://google')]
```

Comment: That is a nice solution but don't think it will find the elements any faster then what I already have, the reason it takes forever to find the elements on the page is that it's single page, so everything is loaded in so it's a massive amount of elements to look through.

Comment: then your requirements are unrealistic, and you do not completely understand Selenium.  This is using what the Selenium API has.. There is no _faster_ way.  If it takes you forever to look through a page of code, then there is something else going on that you don't know about.

Comment: Well I am new to selenium so ofcourse there are some things I don't fully understand about how selenium works, all I knwo is that when I use the code in the example and the item is not there it takes a verry long time but if the item is there it's alot faster. I don't know if selenium tries more then once to search through the DOM for a element if it does not find it but my logic says it should take the same amount of time to see if it exist or not, if i do the search on a small part of the DOM as the edit shows

Comment: give this framework a try.. it's for beginners to selenium and i think you'll find it very nice.  I use this type of framework in production enterprise environments.  consider this the _open source version_ `;)`