# Failover to JavascriptExecutor when Selenium2 findElement fails?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have this idea for failing over to a JavascriptExecutor if Selenium2 fails to retrieve a WebElement object after polling for a limited time.   As you can see, the method has the limitation of needing the "failover" Javascript snippet to be pre-defined when calling getElementByLocator.  I could not think of any way to dynamically do this.   If anyone can help me improve on this, I will award the answer to the best suggestion, however small it is.

```
// failover example1: "document.getElementById('gbqfb')"
// failover example2: "document.querySelector("div#gbqfb")"
public static WebElement getElementByLocator(final By locator, String failover) {
  Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class,StaleElementReferenceException.class);
  WebElement we = wait.until( ExpectedConditions
      .presenceOfElementLocated( locator ) );
  if ( we.isNull() ) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    if ( !failover.isEmpty() ) {
      we = (WebElement)js.executeScript( failover );
      if ( we.isNull() ) LOG.info("Still couldn't get element.");
    } else {
      LOG.info("No failover String available.  Cannot try with " +
        "a JavascriptExecutor.");
    }    
  }
  return we;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255752/fastest-way-to-locate-elements-seleniumjava/19258824#19258824)

I wouldn't recommend delegating anything to javascript like that.. Use what Selenium gives you.. it's very sufficient.

Something that I put in every single framework i've ever built, which is VERY efficient.. Here is an exerpt from the framework found [here](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium).

I implement sort of a pseudo-wait type method before i ever perform any actions on objects. Try it yourself. It's very efficient.

These are methods from the [AutomationTest](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/blob/master/src/main/java/com/company/seleniumframework/AutomationTest.java) class

```
/**
 * Checks if the element is present or not.<br>
 * @param by
 * @return <i>this method is not meant to be used fluently.</i><br><br.
 * Returns <code>true</code> if the element is present. and <code>false</code> if it's not.
 */
public boolean isPresent(By by) {
    if (driver.findElements(by).size() > 0) return true;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Private method that acts as an arbiter of implicit timeouts of sorts.. sort of like a Wait For Ajax method.
 */
private WebElement waitForElement(By by) {
    int attempts = 0;
    int size = driver.findElements(by).size();

    while (size == 0) {
        size = driver.findElements(by).size();
        if (attempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS) fail(String.format("Could not find %s after %d seconds",
                                                         by.toString(),
                                                         MAX_ATTEMPTS));
        attempts++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second.
        } catch (Exception x) {
            fail("Failed due to an exception during Thread.sleep!");
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (size > 0) System.err.println("WARN: There are more than 1 " + by.toString() + " 's!");

    return driver.findElement(by);
}
```

What I do, is anytime i perform something, like

```
getText(By.cssSelector("input#someId"))
```

if it doesn't find it the first time, it'll wait 1 second.  if it finds it then, continues.  does that subsequently 5 times, so a total of 5 seconds wait.. which is perfectly ok because if you DONT find the element you need, then your test effectively should fail at that point.

Also, from experience, i can tell you that using `driver.findElements()` is more effective than those `WebDriverWait`'s.

That doesn't mean i don't use them.. just not for that.  Unfortunately, I had not added this functionality to the getting started with selenium framework, so i'll just tell you when i used Webdriverwait's.

So my test would look like -

```
@Config(url="http://systemunder.test", browser=CHROME)
public class MyClass extends AutomationTest {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        setText(By.id("blah")) // if <* id="blah" /> doesn't exist, waits 1+ seconds for it to appear before interacting.
        .click(By.id("Blah2")) // ^ same thing here.
        .waitForPresent(By.cssSelector("ajaxy")); // this method right here would circumvent the hard waits, with webdriverwait's.
    }
}
```

i don't remember exactly *why* it didn't work for me before, but using webdriverwaits in something like that, is flawless.

Comment: I appreciate the long answer and the very detailed information.  The purpose of my question is to catch the rare edge cases, which in my experience happen sometimes after upgrading from one version of Selenium2 to another, where sometimes a Element is no longer retrievable by the regular script and I am trying to avoid small edits to code in those cases that requires a JavascriptExecutor in order to access it.   Therefore, trying to come up with a working failover method.  As you see from my code, 99% of the time, it doesn't call the JavascriptExecutor.  The failover is just for the edge case.

Comment: I've never in my days as a test engineer ran into this type of issue was not rectified using what I've provided above.  You say that the element is "no longer retrievable by the regular script".. what does that mean?  you provide a selector to select the object, and you're good to go..

Comment: Well, I am saying that my usual code works more than 99% of the time and I use methods similar to yours but maybe slightly more modern (since I use things like FluentWait, ExpectedConditions, LoadableComponent, etc.) but I am also saying that in my experience the .findElement() is quite often not 100% completely reliable.  I want to come up with something that I can say is rock solid.  When writing a framework, this is the goal for the users of your framework.  Also, there is no reason to think that .findElement would be 100% because loading the DOM is not 100%, nor is it  instantaneous...

Comment: Well, I guess we seem to have reached an impasse :)  I've never experienced a time where `findElement()` hasn't worked, and where these methods haven't worked, even with ajax that takes several seconds to load.

Comment: Ok, I hear you.  Next time I see the issue, I will test your theory.